# Compression/optimization text with given structure

Tags: algorithm, optimization, compression

I need to compress(or optimize?) a text file with a structure given. Example of the structure:

```
[string][space][date in format yyyy-MM-dd][space][string]
```

So a string from this text file would look like this:

```
some text 2014-10-26 other text
```

My question is how can I use the given structure for creating a compression algorithm? Like, I need to do some transformations on the original text file to make it weight less, how the structure of this file can help?

I've found one thing called "Structural Contexts with a Semistatic Model", but still don't have an idea how to do my task.

Comment: I don´t see this structure helping much, you are doing text compression basically

Comment: assuming the lines are ordered, you could potentially store the "delta days" instead of the entire date in the consecutive entries. This will save you significant bytes.